# How to Run a Simple Airflow DAG

Tags: python, airflow

I am totally new to Airflow. I would like to run a simple DAG at a specified date. I'm struggling to make difference between the start date, the execution date, and backfilling. And what is the command to run the DAG?

Here is what I've tried since:

```
airflow run dag_1 task_1 2017-1-23
```

The first time I ran that command, the task executed correctly, but when I tried again it did not work.

Here is another command I ran:

```
airflow backfill dag_1 -s 2017-1-23 -e 2017-1-24
```

I don't know what to expect from this command. Will the DAGs execute every day from 23 to 24?

Before running the two commands above, I did this:

```
airflow initdb
airflow scheduler 
airflow webserver -p 8085 --debug &
```

Here is my DAG

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2017, 1, 23, 12),
    'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    'dag_1', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(1))

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='create_clients',
    bash_command='Rscript /scripts/Cli.r',
    dag=dag)

t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='create_operation',
    bash_command='Rscript Operation.r',
    retries=3,
    dag=dag)

t2.set_upstream(t1)
```

Screenshot:[Tree View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBhF6.png)

**UPDATE**

```
airflow run dag_1 task_1 2017-1-23T10:34
```

Comment: If you've actually tried something, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you run it once with the

```
airflow run dag_1 task_1 2017-1-23
```

The run is saved and running it again won't do anything you can try to re-run it by forcing it

```
airflow run --force=true dag_1 task_1 2017-1-23
```

The airflow backfill command will run any executions that would have run in the time period specified from the start to end date.  It will depend what schedule you set on the DAG, if you set it to trigger every hour it should run 24 times, but it also won't re-execute previously executed runs.

You can clear the task as if it NEVER ran

```
airflow clear dag_1 -s 2017-1-23 -e 2017-1-24
```

Also check the cli docs here: https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/cli.html

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I tried to add time to the first run (see update). Why does the run executes immediately even if the time specified is not reached ? By example my current time is 10:30 and i specify 10:34 in the run...It runs immediately, is it normal behaviour?

Comment: I believe(not 100% sure) that it runs the task as if it were that specified date since you passed it in as an argument.  So when it completes, the information saved regarding the run says it completed a run of that task at that time.

Comment: `-f` option will do, no need to set `=true`. Airflow 1.9 `airflow run: error: argument -f/--force: ignored explicit argument 'true'`

Comment: For latest airflow they have replaced `airflow run` with `airflow tasks run` [doc](https://fig.io/manual/airflow/tasks/run)

Answer (score 9):

> difference between the start date ,the execution date and backfilling

Backfilling is done to run DAG explicitly to test/manually run DAG/re run a DAG which error-ed out. You do this using CLI

```
airflow backfill -s <<start_date>> <<dag>> 
#optionally provide -1 as start_date to run it immediately
```

**start_date** is, as the name suggests, date from when the DAG definition is valid

**execution_date** is the date-time when it is to be run. This you provide while testing individual tasks of DAG as below

```
airflow test <<dag>> <<task>> <<exec_date>>
```

> what is the command to run the dag

**Backfill** is the command to run DAG explicitly. Otherwise you just put the DAG in the DAGBAG folder and the scheduler will run it as per the schedule defined in the DAG definition

```
airflow backfill -s <<start_date>> <<dag>> 
#optionally provide -1 as start_date to run it immediately
```

Answer (score 1):

For more recent versions of Airflow you should use `airflow tasks run`.

For example: `airflow tasks run dag_1 task_1 2023-1-3`

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Airflow in Docker, as described at the [official tutorial](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html). I also installed the `airflow.sh` script described [at the end of the page](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#running-the-cli-commands)

What worked for me was the following:

1. List the available DAGS (id their ids)

   ```
   ./airflow.sh dags list
   ```
2. Run the DAG

   ```
   ./airflow.sh dags trigger my_dag --conf '{"manual_execution": true}'
   ```

   Which will output a nicely formatted MD table and will show in the DAGs runs in the UI.