# Debugging Broken DAGs

Tags: airflow

When the airflow webserver shows up errors like `Broken DAG: [<path/to/dag>] <error>`, how and where can we find the full stacktrace for these exceptions?

I tried these locations:

`/var/log/airflow/webserver` -- had no logs in the timeframe of execution, other logs were in binary and decoding with `strings` gave no useful information.

`/var/log/airflow/scheduler` -- had some logs but were in binary form, tried to read them and looked to be mostly sqlalchemy logs probably for airflow's database.

`/var/log/airflow/worker` -- shows up the logs for running DAGs, (same as the ones you see on the airflow page)

and then also under `/var/log/airflow/rotated` -- couldn't find the stacktrace I was looking for.

I am using airflow v1.7.1.3

Comment: For those using [docker-airflow](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow), you can `exec -it` into the `scheduler` container and look for logs in `logs/scheduler/` folder

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Usually I used the command `airflow list_dags` which print the full stacktrace for python error found in dags.

That will work with almost any airflow command as airflow parse dags folder each time you use a airflow CLI command.

Comment: While your solution sounds apt, I'm unable to leverage it in my *dev environment*, where I'm using [docker-airflow](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow). WebUI is reporting `"..not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1).."` in my DAG file (no line number, though) but `list_dags` command runs into [sqlAlchemy.OperationalError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941757/sqlalchemy-exc-operationalerror-sqlite3-operationalerror-no-such-table)

Comment: For any commands, don't forget to add or export `AIRFLOW_HOME=/path/to/airflow` if it's a non-standard `AIRFLOW_HOME` path

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I needed to examine and troubleshoot via looking at the TraceBack. Make sure to get "inside" the container environment you used `docker exec -it DOCKER_ID bash` - once there, run the command listed as the answer here!

Comment: The real question is how do I install the CLI on a remote machine to use on our Kubernetes based Airflow instance? There's hints of possible documentation about this but when I found it and followed it, no such luck at getting any of it to work. Wild goose chase.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle I would recommend asking a new question for that, as your case is a bit more complex (you need to execute `airflow list_dags` on the actual airflow instance. I'm not sure airflow cli can connect to a remote instance.

Comment: As of airflow 2.0, this command no longer exists. `airflow dags list` does not return broken dags either. @Chengzhi's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to compile and see any syntax error, you can also try `python your_dag.py`

Comment: If you're using any connections outside of tasks, be aware that the connections table will not be available doing this, and you'll get a `OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: connection`

Comment: update answer to include "run this from the host/container running the webserver" and it should be the accepted answer as of airflow 2.1.0 (perhaps earlier)

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is access the inner logs of the webserver so that you get the full stacktrace. My Airflow server is being executed in a Docker image so I'll use Docker to fetch these logs but the idea remains.

1. `docker ps`
2. fetch the PID of the webserver
3. `docker logs [PID]`
4. read the full logs of the given Airflow webserver.

This should contain the exact information of why your DAG build failed.

Answer (score 1):

Getting reported `Broken DAG`-error or other `importErrors` can also be done through the [airflow-API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.2/stable-rest-api-ref.html#tag/ImportError)

Example with `curl`:

```bash
# Assuming the airflow instance is running locally on port 8080, with 
# Airflow version 2.2.2
# AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND=airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth
# user: admin
# password: test
# 
# Piping trough `jq` extracting only the stack_trace

curl -s \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --user "admin:test" \
  "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/importErrors" \
    | jq -r '.import_errors[].stack_trace'
```

Might need to enable [access to the API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.2/security/api.html#api-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

I try below following step by step

- `airflow list_dags` as mentioned by @Babcool this will list stacktrace

If you are still not able to figure out issue you run task manually and see direct errors.

pre-step set you environment variables

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME="/airflow/project/path"
export PYTHONPATH="/airflow/project/path"
```

Running dag

```
airflow run dag_id task_id 2020-1-11
```

source:

- [airflow doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli-ref#run)
- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41817854/9592801)

If still things aren't clear you can try running code line by line in python console and check exact issue (after activating your virtual environment)

For example:

```
(venv) shakeel@workstation:~$ python
Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 18 2020, 06:24:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from my_package.my_module import MyClass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944741/debugging-broken-dags/65037325#46615319) works in almost all cases to validate DAGs and debug errors if any.

However, if you are using `docker-compose` to run airflow, you should do this:

```
docker-compose exec airflow airflow list_dags
```

It runs the same command inside the running container.