# Flask in factory pattern cannot find user table in existing database by launching the app

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, factory-pattern

I followed some tutorial of flask factory pattern and tried to refactor my project. The database I use is a MySql container. Everything works fine before refactoring.

Now I came into an error `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user` and I guess the problem is due to isolated `db` instance because I never use sqllite in my project. But I fail to debug it. I also use blutprint to orgnize the strcture.

Here is the code relating to the error:

baseClasses.py

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager

db = SQLAlchemy()
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = "login"
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'
bcrypt = Bcrypt()

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    usr = db.Column(db.String(50),primary_key=True,unique=True,nullable=False)
    psd = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    role = db.Column(db.String(50), default="viewer")  

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.usr}','{self.psd}','{self.role}')"

    def get_id(self):
        return (self.usr)

class DataModel(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True

    own_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement = True, nullable = False) 
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable = False)
    project = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable = False)
    last_user = db.Column(db.String(50))
    path = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable = False)
```

model.py, the class TO is one example of all other classes, each of them has a table in the database.

```
from storage_flask.baseClasses import DataModel
from storage_flask.baseClasses import db

class TO(DataModel):
    __tablename__ = "to"
    
    to_version = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable = False)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable = False)
    issue_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default = datetime.now().date())
    change_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default = datetime.now().date())

def __repr__(self):
    return f"TO('{self.own_id}','{self.name}','{self.to_version}','{self.project}','{self.last_user}','{self.issue_date}','{self.change_date}','{self.path}','{self.title}'"
```

config.py

```
import os

class BaseConfig:
    SECRET_KEY = 'aafa4f8047ce31126011638be8530da6'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

class DevelopmentConfig(BaseConfig):
    DEBUG = True
    #Database
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = 'mysql+pymysql://root:demo@localhost:33065/TO'
```

**init**.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from storage_flask.baseClasses import db, bcrypt, login_manager, User
from storage_flask.main.routes import main

def create_app(config):
    
    #create app instance
    app = Flask(__name__.split('.')[0],static_folder="static")
    app.config.from_object(config)

    db.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    #register blueprintes
    app.register_blueprint(main)

    return app
```

run.py

```
from storage_flask import create_app, config

app = create_app(config.DevelopmentConfig)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", debug=True)
```

routes.py of the blueprint main

```
from flask import render_template, url_for, flash, redirect, request, make_response, jsonify, abort, send_from_directory, Blueprint
# import flask-login functions
from flask_login import login_user, current_user, logout_user, login_required
main = Blueprint('main',__name__)
@main.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def select_function():
    return render_template('functionSelect.html', title = 'Function Selection')
```

The structure of the project would be:

```
|--storage_flask/
|  |--main/
|  |  |--routes.py
|  |--__init__.py
|  |--baseClasses.py
|  |--config.py
|  |--model.py
|--run.py
```

I tried many ways to debug it but I always get the error. The database exists and it works before refactoring with factory pattern.

Could someone give me a hand?

Comment: Did you run flask db init , flask db migrate , flask db upgrade before running the application?

Comment: @dineshh912 No I didn't. It confuses me why is it needed. If I donot use factory pattern I can run the app anytime. The factory pattern does not change any databases I use. Would you please explain a little bit?

Comment: All those three commands basically will look for models in the app and generate tables on the database according to the models.

Comment: @dineshh912But I have already tables and data in the database. Can't they directly connect the database and find the table?

Comment: db you are creating unaware of the models which you generate, try db.create_all()  after the model initialize that should solve the problem, refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941757/sqlalchemy-exc-operationalerror-sqlite3-operationalerror-no-such-table