# Error : sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table:

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

Base.html

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Todo App</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div style="margin-top: 50px;" class="ui container">
     <h1 class="ui center aligned header">To Do App</h1>

     <form class="ui form" action="/add" method="post">
         <div class="field">
             <label>Todo Title</label>
             <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter Todo..."><br>
         </div>
         <button class="ui blue button" type="submit">Add</button>
     </form>

     <hr>

     {% for todo in todo_list %}
     <div class="ui segment">
         <p class="ui big header">{{todo.id }} | {{ todo.title }}</p>

         {% if todo.complete == False %}
         <span class="ui gray label">Not Complete</span>
         {% else %}
         <span class="ui green label">Completed</span>
         {% endif %}

         <a class="ui blue button" href="/update/{{ todo.id }}">Update</a>
         <a class="ui red button" href="/delete/{{ todo.id }}">Delete</a>
     </div>
     {% endfor %}
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

app.py

---

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

# /// = relative path, //// = absolute path
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100))
    complete = db.Column(db.Boolean)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    todo_list = Todo.query.all()
    return render_template("base.html", todo_list=todo_list)


@app.route("/add", methods=["POST"])
def add():
    title = request.form.get("title")
    new_todo = Todo(title=title, complete=False)
    db.session.add(new_todo)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for("home"))


@app.route("/update/<int:todo_id>")
def update(todo_id):
    todo = Todo.query.filter_by(id=todo_id).first()
    todo.complete = not todo.complete
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for("home"))


@app.route("/delete/<int:todo_id>")
def delete(todo_id):
    todo = Todo.query.filter_by(id=todo_id).first()
    db.session.delete(todo)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for("home"))

    @app.before_first_request
    def create_tables():
        db.create_all()


#if __name__ == "__main__":
    #db.create_all()
   # app.run(debug=True)
```

Steps followed:

```
$ mkdir myproject
$ cd myproject
$ python3 -m venv venv
```

Activate it

```
$ . venv/bin/activate
```

or on Windows

```
venv\Scripts\activate
```

Install Flask

```
$ pip install Flask
$ pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy
```

Set environment variables in terminal

```
$ export FLASK_APP=app.py
$ export FLASK_ENV=development
```

or on Windows

```
$ set FLASK_APP=app.py
$ set FLASK_ENV=development
```

Run the app

```
$ flask run
```

Error message:

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: todo [SQL: SELECT todo.id AS todo_id, todo.title AS todo_title, todo.complete AS todo_complete  FROM todo] (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/errors.html#error-e3q8), **`OperationalError`** occurs when the api is unable to resolve a driver. From your code, one possible troubleshoot might be to rename this line in app.py:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite' # <--- remove this
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite3'# <--- add this
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
```

**The reason:**
The connection might not be well established and must have failed to create the required db. The above suggested edits might resolve this issue

**EDIT:** If the above answer doesn't work for you, checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941757/sqlalchemy-exc-operationalerror-sqlite3-operationalerror-no-such-table?rq=1).

Comment: Ok, then I recommend you to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941757/sqlalchemy-exc-operationalerror-sqlite3-operationalerror-no-such-table?rq=1).

Try putting all the database related codes in a file called models.py and invoke it in the main file using an import. The above answer is suggesting that the db might be used in different contexts depending on the scenario. So, its better to call `db.create_all()` from within the modles.py file

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, if this is the first time you are building this application, that you haven't ever created the databases in the first place.

I was following the Flask Mega Tutorial and got a similar error to what you have:

```
qlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: todo
```

In this tutorial there is a section about creation migration scripts that I could not get to work so I skipped that.  Apparently this creates the databases.  So the solution for me was from the Python Console I ran the following codes:

```
from app import db
from app.models import User, Posts
db.create_all()
u = User(username='admin', email='admin@email.com')
db.session.add(u)
db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

ADDING THE FIRST RECORD
In order to add the first record in the database and avoid the above error, your first route where you have the index.html should not have anything related to the database on the first run:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

After the first run, and after adding the first record (from the web), you can now add anything related to the database that you want on the home page.

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
   posts = TaskPost.query.all()
   return render_template("index.html", all_posts=posts)
```