# flask-sqlalchemy 3 gives 'OperationalError: no such table' after update

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I've got a Flask app with multiple SQLALCHEMY_BINDS. Since upgrading to 3.0.3, Flask-SQLAlchemy gives an error whenever I try and query any of the databases in SQLALCHEMY_BINDS, but the main database is working fine.

The error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: playlist
```

python is 3.11.3, Flask is 2.2.4, Flask-SQLAlchemy is 3.0.3. All the same code works fine in the main not-yet-upgraded code environment.

I've been reading through the [release notes for Flask-SQLAlchemy 3.0](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/changes/) and I have yet to find anything that suggests the source of the problem.

I did come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75784852/flask-sqlalchemy-cant-find-tables-after-upgrading-from-2-5-to-3-x) which seems related, except my sqlite connection is defined with an absolute, not relative path. I messed around with the path just to see if I could get anywhere, but the app seems clear on working vs broken paths.

F-SA knows the the database info too, there's just something Wrong and I'm out of steam. This all started trying to get a new-in-python-3.11 method out of string.Template, and now I'm so far down the rabbit hole I can no longer see the sun.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
>>> db.metadatas.get('swinsian')
MetaData()
>>> db.metadatas.get('swinsian').__dict__
{'tables': FacadeDict({'track': Table('track', MetaData(), Column('track_id', Integer(), table=<track>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('album', Text(), table=<track>), schema=None), 'playlist': Table('playlist', MetaData(), Column('playlist_id', Integer(), table=<playlist>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('name', Text(), table=<playlist>), schema=None), 'playlistfolderplaylist': Table('playlistfolderplaylist', MetaData(), Column('playlistfolder_id', Integer(), table=<playlistfolderplaylist>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('playlist_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('playlist.playlist_id'), table=<playlistfolderplaylist>), schema=None), 'topplaylist': Table('topplaylist', MetaData(), Column('topplaylist_id', Integer(), table=<topplaylist>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('playlist_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('playlist.playlist_id'), table=<topplaylist>), schema=None), 'playlisttrack': Table('playlisttrack', MetaData(), Column('id', Integer(), table=<playlisttrack>, primary_key=True, nullable=False), Column('playlist_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('playlist.playlist_id'), table=<playlisttrack>), Column('track_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('track.track_id'), table=<playlisttrack>), Column('tindex', Integer(), table=<playlisttrack>), schema=None)}), 'schema': None, 'naming_convention': immutabledict({'ix': 'ix_%(column_0_label)s'}), 'info': {'bind_key': 'swinsian'}, '_schemas': set(), '_sequences': {}, '_fk_memos': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {('playlist', 'playlist_id'): [ForeignKey('playlist.playlist_id'), ForeignKey('playlist.playlist_id'), ForeignKey('playlist.playlist_id')], ('track', 'track_id'): [ForeignKey('track.track_id')]})}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved; it was a problem with the app install script, and not the upgrade/versions themselves.

A bug in click 8.1.3 sent me down the versioning rabbit hole. Docs claiming `db.create_all()` would save the day only complicated things.

In fact, the tables were missing from the newly installed database, and once I realized it I was able to work through the rest of the version conflicts.