# Debugging broken dags in GCP Composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have read the [question for vanilla Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944741/debugging-broken-dags).

How can broken DAGs be debugged effectively in Google Cloud Composer?
How can i see the full logs of a broken DAG?

Right now I can only see one line of trace in Airflow UI main page.

**EDIT:**
Answers seem to be **not understanding my question**.
I am looking for fixing **broken DAGs** i.e. the DAG does not even appear in the DAGs list and of course there are no tasks running and no task logs to view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As hexacynide pointed out, you can look at the task logs - there's details in the Composer docs about doing that specifically found [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/logs). You can also use [Stackdriver logging](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/monitoring-environments), which is enabled by default in Composer projects. In Stackdriver logs, you can filter your logs on many variables, including by time, by pod (airflow-worker, airflow-webserver, airflow-scheduler, etc.) and by whatever keywords you suspect might appear in the logs.

**EDIT: Adding screenshots and more clarity in response to question update**

In Airflow, when there's a broken DAG, there is usually some form of error message at the top. (Yes, I know this error message is helpful and I don't need to debug further, but I'm going to just to show how to)

In the message, I can see that my DAG bq_copy_across_locations is broken.

[image: Airflow Web UI with "Broken DAG" Error message]

To debug, I go to Stackdriver, and search for the name of my DAG. I limit the results to the logs from this Composer environment. You can also limit the time frame if needed.

[image: Stackdriver logs with DAG name in search bar]

I looked through the error logs and found a the Traceback error for the broken DAG.

[image: Logs with traceback line highlighted]

Alternatively, if you know you only want to search for the stack traceback, you can run an advanced filter looking for your DAG name and the word "traceback". To do so, click the arrow at the right side of the Stackdriver logging bar and hit "convert to advance filter"

[image: Stackdriver logs with arrow pointing to convert to advance filter]

Then enter your advanced filter

```
resource.type="cloud_composer_environment"
resource.labels.location="YOUR-COMPOSER-REGION"
resource.labels.environment_name="YOUR-ENV-NAME"
("BROKEN-DAG-NAME" AND
"Traceback")
```

This is what my advanced search looked like

[image: Advanced filter for traceback logs]

The only logs that will be returned will be the stack Traceback logs for that DAG.

[image: Tracebacks in Stackdriver logs]

Answer (score 1):

To determine run-time issues that occur when a DAG is triggered, you can always look at task logs as you would for any typical Airflow installation. These can be found using the web UI, or by looking in the associated logs folder in your Cloud Composer environment's associated Cloud Storage bucket.

To identify issues at parse time, you can execute Airflow commands using `gcloud composer`. For example, to run `airflow list_dags`, the `gcloud` CLI equivalent would be:

```sh
$ gcloud composer environments --location=$REGION run $ENV_NAME -- list_dags --report
```

Note that the second `--` is intentional. This is so that the command argument parser can differentiate between arguments to `gcloud` and arguments to be passed to the Airflow subcommand (in this case `list_dags`).

Comment: Just a quick comment if somebody else is here and was getting errors with the above command. Not sure if it's changed or was wrong to begin with but the one that worked for me is:
 `$ gcloud composer environments run $ENV_NAME --location=$REGION list_dags`
I couldn't get the --report flag to work with the SUBCOMMAND but the above gave me a better stack trace to debug my broken dag!