# How to use Airflow with Pywikibot

Tags: python, airflow, pywikibot

When importing `pywikibot` in a DAG file (or a module the DAG file imports), the DAG becomes broken, throwing the error in the webserver UI:

```
Broken DAG: [/path/to/airflow/dags/dag.py] encode() argument 1 must be str, not bool
```

I have tried to find a stack trace, but couldn't find anything by doing a search in `airflow/logs`. Running `airflow list_dags` runs successfully and doesn't help debugging the problem (as recommended by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944741/debugging-broken-dags)), even with `--report`.

**My question is thus: how can I use Pywikibot in a task of an Airflow DAG?**

---

I've added additional information below to show what I've tried thus far. After we find the answer, this can be deleted to make the question more consise.

---

Here is the code for an example DAG:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

#### this part is typically imported from another module ####
# to import, pywikibot requires `user-config.py` file or this env variable
import os
os.environ['PYWIKIBOT_NO_USER_CONFIG'] = '1'
import pywikibot
def do_nothing():
    pass
#############################################################

dag = DAG('try_pywikibot', schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1))

default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(2019,1,1),
}

task1 = PythonOperator(
    python_callable=do_nothing,
    task_id=f'do_nothing',
    dag=dag,
    default_args=default_args,
)
```

---

Note on importing `pywikibot`:
Pywikibot demands a config file, `user-config.py`, in the working directory, unless a `PYWIKIBOT_NO_USER_CONFIG` env variable is specified as `0`. Example of such a file:

```
family = 'wikipedia' # required
mylang = 'en' # required
# verbose_output = 0  # optional
```

---

I thought it might be because of `pywikibot`'s logging (sending a `bool`?). Verbose logging can be turned off by adding `verbose_output = 0` in `pywikibot`'s config file (`user-config.py`), but this does not resolve the matter.

Oddly, running this simple script

```
import pywikibot
import airflow
```

with a `user-config.py` file with `verbose_output=0` still outputs verbose logs from `pywikibot`. But, when not import Airflow, it runs through without any logging output. However, I've tried completely disabling logging from `pywikibot` by modifying the library's `logging.logoutput()`, which disables the logging even with Airflow imported, but the DAG is still regarded as broken by Airflow.

---

The DAG does "start" when manually triggering the DAG, but the tasks are never queued; they remain stuck in state `None`.

Comment: I've notice that when I use `logging.basicConfig('` it turns to verbose mode and I don't understand why...

Answer (score 1):

Adding the line `console_encoding="utf-8"` to pywikibot's config, `user-config.py`, does the trick.

---

Why exactly, I'm not sure. When run through Airflow, Pywikibot seems to fail loading it's default value for `console_encoding`, `utf-8`. Becuase pywikibot's `transliterator` is eager loaded, this cause a failure in `pywikbot.userinterfaces.transliteration.py` at ln. 1108.

Oddly enough, pywikibot seems to expect a boolean value and now throws

```
_DifferentTypeError: Configuration variable "console_encoding" is defined as "str" in your user-config.py but expected "bool".
```

However, this can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1. The framework's `config2.py` has been changed which never should be done.
2. The Pywikibot is probably outdated. `console_encoding`is `sys.stdout.encoding`by default and should be `'utf-8'`.

It depends on your Python and Pywikibot version.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and google brought me here.
This solution will not solve your problem, which as it seems, you solved differently. However, this might help others:

https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T272088

The workaround is to init the logger and change the logLevel of pywiki:

```py
import logging
import pywikibot
pywikibot.output('This will initialize the logger')
logger = logging.getLogger('pywiki')
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

This is a workaround until it's fixed!

Just a friendly advance for next time, if you would state which python/pywikibot version you use, it can help others too ;)