# Airflow Debugging broken DAGs new CLI

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to debug a `Broken DAG` message from the airflow UI, from the accepted answer of [Debugging Broken DAGs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944741/debugging-broken-dags).

**However, with airflow 2.1.0,** the `airfow list_dags` command now prints a usage message:

> usage: airflow [-h] GROUP_OR_COMMAND ...

`airflow dags list` and `airflow dags report` both give a table with DAGs, but none give the full stack trace I'm looking for.

```sh
$ airflow dags report

file             | duration       | dag_num | task_num | dags
=================+================+=========+==========+=================
/myBROKENDAG.py  | 0:00:00.032594 | 0       | 0        |
/example-dag.py  | 0:00:00.009614 | 1       | 9        | example_dag
/mydag2.py       | 0:00:00.007147 | 1       | 1        | mydag2
```

Any ideas on how to find the full stack trace for a broken DAG with the new CLI?

Comment: note that I'm using a UI-defined connection pre-DAG definition

Answer (score 1):

What I could figure so far, is from the container or host running the airflow webserver:

```sh
cd dags
python myBROKENDAG.py
```

this also accounted for the UI-defined connection and printed the full stacktrace.

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46695788/3517025)