# How tu run a DAG automatically

Tags: python, celery, airflow

I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41805265/how-to-run-a-simple-airflow-dag), and I could successfully run a **DAG** using the following command `airflow backfill -s -1 pipeline`, however it's a manual execution. I'd like to know how to execute my dags in an specific interval and automatically. I am novice with this and I'm still stuck. I also read this [guide](http://tech.marksblogg.com/airflow-postgres-redis-forex.html), but apparently the writer uses `Celery` to execute the dags and I have some issues regarding it, for instance when I try to run `airflow worker` it says I have a port used, I could solve it by downgrading `Celery` as they say [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-749). Nevertheless, when I try to run it again I get even more errors.

Notice that when I defined my `DAG`, I tried to run it every 2 minutes.

```
dag = DAG(dag_id='pipeline',
          default_args=args,
          schedule_interval='*/2 * * * *',
          dagrun_timeout=timedelta(seconds=30))
```